# Components not reacting to nested mobx stores

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I'm rendering a square based off a nested store (`SquareModel`) in MobX. When the square is clicked I would like an action to fire within `SquareModel`, changing a `selected` property which would, in turn, resize the square. However, I can't seem to get the square to react to the property change. Any ideas on how to get this working?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/m51oyzz069

MainStore:

```js
import { observable, decorate } from "mobx";
import SquareModel from "./SquareModel";

class MobXStore {
  square = new SquareModel();
}

decorate(MobXStore, {
  square: observable
});

export default new MobXStore();
```

NestedStore:

```js
import { observable, action, decorate } from "mobx";

class SquareModel {
  selected = false;
  toggleSelection() {
    console.log("toggle selection");
    this.selected = !this.selected;
  }
}

decorate(SquareModel, {
  selected: observable,
  toggleSelection: action
});

export default SquareModel;
```

React:

```js
const App = observer(() => {
  return (
    <svg className="App">
      <svg x={100} y={100}>
        <Square
          unit={MobXStore.square.selected ? 2 : 1}
          onPointerUp={MobXStore.square.toggleSelection}
        />
      </svg>
    </svg>
  );
});

export const Square = observer(({ unit, ...props }) => {
  console.log("render square");
  return (
    <g {...props}>
      <rect height={unit * 50} width={unit * 50} style={{ fill: "blue" }} />
    </g>
  );
});
```

Comment: Where do you provide `MobXStore` ? Import its instance doesn't work, you have to use `<Provider>` from `mobx-react`. https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#provider-and-inject

Comment: I don't think a provider is necessary in this scenario - it doesn't really make a difference anyway https://codesandbox.io/s/73lmp636rj

Comment: I'm using a newer version of mobx so I can uitilise hooks - the syntax is similar to https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-lite#why-no-providerinject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error with "this" in the toggleSelection method

It should look like:

```
onPointerUp = {() => MobXStore.square.toggleSelection()}
```

or you need to use, for example, the arrow function here:

```
toggleSelection = () => {
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)